# How to improve the performance in big table join?

Tags: join, bitmap, bigdata, vertica

Please help me out with this big data problem.

I have a very large table (500G) that stores cookie information collected from one website, and I try to provide service to many other clients. For each client, they have their cookies, so in the end I need to do query on 500G+300G(client_data).

Since some query use both my cookie data and client cookie data, it is possible that I need to do a join between my table and their table, therefore the performance is bad. To solve this problem, I put the entire 800GB data into a giant table. Since there is no join table, the performance is good. But when I expand my service to multiple client, it takes too much storage.

Current I am using Vertica as my data source, and use bitmap to store my information.

Any suggestion that can maintain my current performance but also support like 40 cients? My storage is about 12 TB and each client in current solution talkes 1.5T.

what I want is either a replacement of Vertica with can support bitmap operation and quick table join. Or a better way to represent my data.

Answer (score 1):

> My storage is about 12 TB and each client in current solution talkes 1.5T.

If you have 40 * 1.5TB worth of non-duplicated cookie data to store, there's no magic to make that fit into 12TB.

Answer (score 1):

This will be an imprecise answer due to the lack of details about definitions, etc. But I would add the following about performance:

Look at your projection definitions. You may be able to get performance gains depending on what you put in the order by clause of the projection.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few ways forward, depending on the specifics of your case. Point 1 and 3 are the easiest to deal with:

1. You can properly set projections, to make sure that both tables are identically segmented: https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#12549.htm
2. You can set up pre join projections, where the join cost is paid during data load, not during data retrieval, see https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#1299.htm
3. Make sure that your data type is the best possible. Matching on ints is faster than matching on strings, matching columns with low cardinality is faster than matching columns with high cardinality.

If 1 and 3 are well set, Vertica can actually apply filters before decompression, fastening  a lot your query and thus using a lot less memory.